# Image stop on other image

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have an image/character for a little mini game. I can make him jump and go left and right. I but I want him to be able to land on other images like super mario landing on the bricks or doodle jump (without the jump). How do I make it so once my image jumps and falls, if it lands on another image it will stop. Thank you!

my jumping code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0.0
                options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
             animations:^{
                 CGRect f = imageView.frame;
                 f.origin.y -= 40;
                 imView.frame = f;
             }
             completion:^(BOOL finished){

[UIView animateWithDuration:.7 delay:0.0
                options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
             animations:^{
                 CGRect f = imageView.frame;
                 f.origin.y += 40;
                 imView.frame = f;
             }
             completion:nil];
```

Comment: Are you using cocos2d? sharing your current code will help.

Comment: Look up 2-D collision detection...that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this can be done with simple `UIView` animations, this is more of a `Cocos` thing. Using this type of animation, there's something you need to keep in mind. Although on screen you see an image animating from one point to another, throughout this process the image only ever actually has two frames. It's frame before the animation starts, and the frame at the end.

Additionally, if you attempt to read the frame of the image once the animation has begun, it will always log its ending position. There are only two frames for an image, before and after. Once the animation starts it's frame is set to its end frame, and it is basically just working on getting there. (animating)

This being said, there's no room for collision detection with this form of animation. Let's look at the following scenario.

> _***A*_**=============**_*B*_**==========**_*C*_**
>
> ^start^-------^path^----^collision --------    ^end

Your animation starts at frame "A" and is set to end at point "C". You want to detect collision at "B" but unfortunately you can't because the image never knows that it's frame ever intersected with "B" because it's only ever aware of points "A" and "C"

Hope this helps!